# CosmosDB Graph: Are per-request consistency levels supported the way they are for documents?

Tags: azure, graph, azure-cosmosdb, gremlin

When using the "original" document API in CosmosDB, there is the possibility to specify a consistency level per request, which can of course be different than the default consistency level for the collection.

Is this supported in the graph API, using either the initial [Graph SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/graph-sdk-dotnet) or  Gremlin.NET ?

More to the point, can I get a session token from the [DocumentClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.documents.client.documentclient?view=azure-dotnet) and reuse it for Gremlin queries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately CosmosDB Gremlin API does not currently support applying consistency levels per-request. Gremlin requests will assume the default consistency level of the Azure CosmosDB account.

If you'd like to see this feature, please add a request [here](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263030-azure-cosmos-db).

It's also helpful for CosmosDB team to get specific use-case details, so please send an email to: *AskCosmosDBGraphAPI@microsoft.com*.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. What about atomicity in a single request? If I create multiple nodes/edges in a single Gremlin request, is it possible that a different instance of a cloud service would see just a subset of the new items?

Comment: Gremlin requests are atomic per-element (a vertex or an edge) but not across all write ops on the request. So if multiple vertices are being written in request A, concurrent request B might read one of vertex rather than both (this is possible for requests executed on the same connection as well as separate connections).